# How to merge 2 dataframe base on a third dataframe containing multiindex

Tags: pandas

I have 2 dataframe and i want to merge them. my join keys are index and they are third dataframe.

the two dataframe :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3] })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B' : ['A','B','C']})
```

the dataframe containing index list:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'C' :[1], 'D' :[2]})
df3 = df3.set_index(['C','D'])
```

desired output :

```
    A   B
0   2   C
```

Comment: This logic isn't obvious to me. How do you know that the first index value is to be taken from `df1`, while the second index chooses from `df2`?

Comment: I guess df3 index name should be A ,B /-:

Comment: no logic :( i just knew it.
i am using the record linkage toolkit to fuzzy match 2 dataframe.
it return me available pair in a daframe.
https://recordlinkage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/link_two_dataframes.html#Compare-records

Comment: instead a third dataframe it could be a list of tuple [(1,2)]. in that case the first number of the tuple is the index of df1 and the second number the index of df2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With tuples in a list:

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3] })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B' : ['A','B','C']})
t = [(1,2), (1,0)]
```

Make df3, with the correct column names:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(t, columns=list(df1.columns)+list(df2.columns))
#   A  B
#0  1  2
#1  1  0
```

Then you can use `lookup` + `pivot` to get the correct value from each frame, and return to the original shape.

```
df3 = df3.stack().reset_index()
df3['vals'] = pd.concat([df1, df2], 1).lookup(df3[0], df3.level_1)
df3 = df3.pivot(index='level_0', columns='level_1', values='vals').rename_axis(None, 1).rename_axis(None, 0)

#   A  B
#0  2  C
#1  2  A
```